# companion method in List

Tags: scala

I notice a method called 'companion' in List class. What does it do? Its definition is 'The factory companion object that builds instances of class List.'

It seems I can create new instances of a List using l.companion(11,12,13) method but why would I do it this way instead of using List(11,12,13)?

```
val l = List[Int](1,2,3,4,1)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1)

val l2 = l.companion
l2: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[List] = scala.collection.immutable.List$@6c3e1f48

//I can create new instances of a List using l2 but why would I do it this way?
val l3 = l2(100,11,123)

l3.foreach(println _)
100
11
123
res0: Unit = ()
```

The object returned from companion can also be used to create mutable collections (Builders). But why would I create collection this way!

```
//create a Builder (a mutable collection) whose elements would be list of strings
val l5 = l2.newBuilder[List[String]]
l5: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[List[String],List[List[String]]] = ListBuffer()

l5+=List("h")
l5+=List("2")

println(l5)
ListBuffer(List(h), List(2))
res3: Unit = ()
```

Comment: probably just for some code reuse in collections library

Comment: maybe. The object returned from companion can also be used to create mutable collections (Builders) but why would I create new list or builders this way!

val l5 = l2.newBuilder[List[String]]
l5: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[List[String],List[List[String]]] = ListBuffer()

l5+=List("h")
l5+=List("2")

println(l5)
ListBuffer(List(h), List(2))
res3: Unit = ()

Answer (score 1):

It's not really meant for you to use in normal circumstances. Many companion objects of collection classes inherit from `GenericCompanion`. Anything that inherits from it must implement `newBuilder`, which provides a `Builder` for the associated collection type. In turn, that collection's companion object inherits the `apply` and `empty` methods, which are used virtually everywhere in the standard collections library.

The (likely) reason every `List` (and many other collections) has a reference to it's own companion is so that it can be used for generics, particularly with higher-kinds.

There is no native way to connect a type with its companion using the type system alone. For example, if you want some `M[A] <: Traversable[A]`, you have no way of finding it's companion (in general, a generic type like this might not even have one). To work around this, we require that the collection itself has a reference to it's own companion (with other type parameters and constraints imposed). It also saves the need to have multiple implementations of `apply` and `empty` copied throughout all of the collections.